# Remove search box within imessage

Tags: ios, messages, iphone

How do you get rid of the search box within the imessage app at the top? I enabled it by doing the following:

In the Messages app, back out to the main view that lists all conversations. Scroll to the top (by tapping on the time at the top of the screen — an eleventh hidden trick for this list!) and then pull down a bit more by tapping the middle of the display and dragging your finger down a bit. You’ll see a hidden search box appear above the first conversation.

How can I reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have revealed it, it stays.  To remove it, you can go into the app switcher (double tap on HOME), and swipe the app away to force it to restart back in the default mode with a hidden search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that is what Apple calls, "expected behavior."

On my phone I only have a few threads in the messages list and the search box is always available. If I scroll up the search box behaves like it is part of the list, it scrolls up off the screen and hides.

Comment: it never did this before until I tapped on the time and dragged down a little, is there a way to reverse that ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't "enable" it. It's just the design of iMessage. You can't get "reverse" it.

Scrolling all the way to the top will reveal it, scrolling down will hide it.